# LSMEANS for Poisson Regression in R

Tags: r, poisson-regression, lsmeans

I have the dataset:

```
structure(list(n = c(0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 
1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), year = c(1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 
1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 
1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 
1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 
1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 
1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 
2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020), 
    location = c("London", "London", "London", "London", "London", 
    "London", "London", "London", "London", "London", "London", 
    "London", "London", "London", "London", "London", "London", 
    "London", "London", "London", "London", "London", "London", 
    "London", "London", "London", "London", "London", "London", 
    "London", "London", "London", "London", "London", "London", 
    "London", "London", "London", "London", "London", "London", 
    "London", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", 
    "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", 
    "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", 
    "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", 
    "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", 
    "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", 
    "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", 
    "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", 
    "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Liverpool", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", 
    "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", 
    "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", 
    "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", 
    "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", 
    "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork", "Cork")), row.names = c(NA, 
-126L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

where I have applied Poisson Regression:

```
summary(p2 <- glm(n ~ location+year, family="poisson", data=test2))
```

and then lsmeans for post hoc analysis:

```
emmeans(p2, pairwise ~ location)
```

I have the following questions:

(1) In the results of lsmeans I see that in the contrast the degrees of freedom are Inf. Why does this happen?

(2) How the individual lsmeans are computed? Can you maybe give a formula? I know that lsmeans is the estimated expected values for an effect assuming all other covariates are at their average level.  Does that mean that year is on the average level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Question**

For standard GLMs, the null distributions of the standardized coefficients are taken to be asymptotically $N(0,1)$ aka $t_{inf}$. Normally the significance of these linear models is computed from a $t_\nu$ distribution, but I suppose for consistent outputs, it makes sense to also just set the degrees of freedom for GLMs at infinity.

**Second Question**
You have specified the following model:

$$
E[log(Y_i)]=\beta_0+\beta_{Year}x_{Year}+\beta_{Loc}x_{Loc}
$$

Suppose you ask to compute the expected value at Location i, then the above reduces to this:

$$
E[log(Y_i)|Loc=Loc_i]=\beta_0+\beta_{Year}x_{Year}+\beta_{Loc_i}
$$

However, you want the marginalized means, so you need to compute the following, where you marginalize out over the remaining variables:

$$
E[E[log(Y_i)|Loc=Loc_i]]=E[\beta_0]+\beta_{Year}E[x_{Year}]+\beta_{Loc_i}
$$

So then your observed marginal mean should be $\beta_0+\beta_{Year}\hat{x}_{Year}+\beta_{Loc_i}$, where $\hat{x}_{Year}$ is the average value of the years. So, the marginal means yields an estimate at the average year value.